# Decoding (Base64 encoded data with type conversion to string by python type casting) to byte array in JAVA

Tags: java, python, websocket, socket.io, base64

Hi I have some problem with type conversion.
First, with python3.7, I read data from imagefile and encoded it as base64 which is then bytes type.
Then, I converted the bytes data to string with type conversion
Python codes are below.

```
f = open("monitor-1.png", "rb")
    data = f.read()
    encoded_string = str(base64.b64encode(data))
```

Then I sent it to java program using socket

To view image from java program,
 need to get byte array from the received data. But what should I do? Type conversion of python makes me confused..

Comment: What did you do so far in *Java*? What are you getting there? Did you try first with some simpler text e.g. "ABCD", to see that it's working?

Comment: I just sent encoded_string via socket to java program and received that string from java

Comment: So you don't know what to do with it? Did you look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html?

Comment: i tried byte result[] = Base64.decode((String)args[0], Base64.DEFAULT); but it triggers java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64..

Comment: In *Python*, try: `encoded_string = base64.b64encode(data)` (no *str*). Not sure how were you able to send a string over a socket in *Python 3*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should provide a snippet which can be used to reproduce your issue.

Following snippets are working

```
import base64
f = open("monitor-1.png", "rb")
data = f.read()
encoded_string = str(base64.b64encode(data))
print(encoded_string)
f.close()
```

output

```
b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABAQMAAADO7O3JAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACklEQVQI12NoAAAAggCB3UNq9AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
```

using the Base64 encoded string in Java `jshell`

```
jshell> byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAABAQMAAADO7O3JAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACklEQVQI12NoAAAAggCB3UNq9AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
bytes ==> byte[85] { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0 ... 8, 68, -82, 66, 96, -126 }

jshell> Files.write(Paths.get("out.png"), bytes)
$2 ==> out.png
```

creates the file `out.png`

The file `monitor-1.png` and `out.png` are equal

```
$ md5sum monitor-1.png out.png 
49b0cecce3c3ce0966afd6c13b03a4b5  monitor-1.png
49b0cecce3c3ce0966afd6c13b03a4b5  out.png
```

Comment: thank you so much! the <b'> part at the head was problem!